# get entries by max date

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `answered` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `question_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `correct` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `questions` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

i need to select count of correct and incorrect answers, BUT: if same question got multiple answers (there may be more entries in "answered" with same question_id) **only the latest** (determined by "answered.created") shall count.

result structure should be like:

```
correct  count 
  0        1 
  1        3
```

Fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/11073

My trial:

```
SELECT a.correct, count(*) as count
FROM answered a 
JOIN questions q ON a.question_id = q.id 
GROUP BY correct
```

this works, but counts same question_ids more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Correct, count(*) as count
FROM questions q
JOIN (select question_id, max(created) as 'MaxCreated' from answered group by question_id) a 
ON a.question_id = q.id 
JOIN answered t1 on a.question_id = t1.question_id and  a.MaxCreated = t1.Created
GROUP BY correct
```

Probably there are better options (I don't like joining by date, what if the dates are repeated?) But I think it will give you what you want (I mean, if you want the max date, you shouldn't have repeated dates)

Answer (score -1):

I believe that there is no way to do it without some cursor, because you want to evaluate each question if it has zero or more answers, and if it does have more than one answer you want to get the most recent, which means that you want to interact on each Question_id.

Check out this code:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html

And for each question Id you check if the latest answer is right or not, than you add in the Right and Wrong variables.